# Styling .NET Core Angular Template (VS) with bootstrap

Tags: css, angular, asp.net-core, bootstrap-4

I have started a new .NET Core template with Angular (with Microsoft identity) and I have started with the UI.

So here I see that the .net core identity uses bootstrap default, and it is not possible to reach that. The solution around that is to create a CSS-folder in "wwwroot", that will be read after the default bootstrap. Even though I would have like to create my own bootstrap theme, I can live with this.

But now I see that the angular lives with a different "theme". Even though it uses many of the same classes I have to define each class in my angular app also in the "styles.scss".
So many classes will be pretty similar (especially if I use NGbootstrap).

So I tried to import "wwwroot/css/site.css" into my styles.scss, so I didn't need to write it twice, that did of course not work.

Is there any way to use the same CSS document in both places, or is that something I should avoid?

[image: Screenshot Visual studio]